# How to rationalise the denominator when it comes out undefined?

Tags: fractions

$$\frac{3-{\sqrt 5}}{\sqrt 5 + 5}$$

This is probably ridiculously straightforward but I need to get to the answer $$ 1-\frac{2}{5}{\sqrt 5}$$

and can't figure out how to rationalise the denominator bc 5 - 5 = 0 and can't have that on the bottom of a fraction. pls help

Comment: $5-5=0$ is irrelevant. $\sqrt 5 - 5$ is not zero ...

Comment: Multiplying by $5-\sqrt5$ the denominator becomes $5^2-5=20 \neq 0$.

Comment: $$5^2-(\sqrt 5)^2 \neq 5-5$$

Comment: A general hint for future work: if you have two real numbers, neither of them is zero, and by multiplying them together you get zero, you made a mistake and should check your work.

Comment: Wait ok maybe I didn't explain well- what I was trying to do was multiply the whole fraction by √5-5. (√5+5)(√5-5) on the bottom of the fraction would be zero because of the difference of squares

Comment: OH hang on I get it, that was so dumb can't believe I didn't see that.. I'm starting maths from scratch and keep making silly mistakes haha. Thanks for your patience and answers!

Answer (score 0):

Write $$\frac{(3-\sqrt{5})(5-\sqrt{5})}{(5+\sqrt{5})(5-\sqrt{5})}=...$$